# "Last check-in" not being updated in chef server

Tags: chef-infra

I'm facing the situation that the "last check-in" time is not being updated at all after I run the "ohai" recipe in the nodes.   I'm running nodes unix, linux and it is the same thing.  I'm using this package/version chef-server-core-12.7.0-1.el7.x86_64.
I've checked via "knife status" and via GUI w/chef manage.

Does anybody know what is the condition that makes that value to get updated ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That value is only updated after the node completes a converge with no errors and without using a `-o` override run list.